# Factory not being loaded in ZF2 - Missing argument 1

Tags: module, zend-framework2, factory, servicemanager, zend-servicemanager

I have a factory within `Module/src/Module/Service/Factory/CourseServiceFactory.php`

I have defined this factory in `module.config.php` as follows:

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'CourseServiceFactory' => 'Module\Service\Factory\CourseServiceFactory',
        ),
),
```

However this factory isn't being loaded upon calling the application and I receive this error:

> **Warning**:  Missing argument 1 for
>   Module\Service\CourseService::__construct(),

This is how my **CourseServiceFactory.php** looks like:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

    return new CourseService($config);
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: How does the call to service locator look like?

Comment: what is the arguments in your  __constructor(), 
 Module\Service\CourseService::__construct(),

Comment: @akond I am sorry what do you mean by call to service locator? Aren't factories loaded on Bootstrap once you define them in module.config.php?

Comment: No, they are not loaded until you explicitly require them from service locator.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're not implementing the factory interface which causes the service loader to be injected into the constructor.

Make sure your factory implements:

Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface

See example factory here

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/services-and-servicemanager.html

Comment: I am implementing the Factory Interface in the Factory